# Change Element Value outside TableView Scope

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

i have a TableView with a customCell. I set the values of the customCell Elements inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. No problem. But i want to change some customCell Element Values outside of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` Scope. For example after a Swipe i want to change the Value of a cell element inside my swipe function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    let cell:customCell = self.tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell")! as customCell
    let rowData: NSDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    let imageSwipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageSwiped:")
        imageSwipeLeft.direction = .Left
    let urlString: NSString = rowData["testImage"] as NSString

    self.indexPathArray += [indexPath]

    cell.testLabel.text = "Test Label"

    cell.testImage.image = image
    cell.testImage.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.testImage.addGestureRecognizer(imageSwipeLeft)
    cell.testImage.userInteractionEnabled = true

    ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(urlString, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
        cell.testImage.image = image
        cell.testImage.layer.borderWidth = 6;
        cell.testImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        cell.testImage.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.placeholderLoading.stopAnimating()
    })

    return cell
}


func imageSwiped(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
   let testData: NSDictionary = self.tableData[recognizer.view.tag] as NSDictionary
   let imageSlide = recognizer.view as UIImageView

   var imageURL = testData["image"] as String
   ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(imageURL, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
        UIView.transitionWithView(imageSlide,
           duration:0.44,
           options: .TransitionCrossDissolve,
           animations: { imageSlide.image = image },
           completion: nil)
   })

   let indexPath = self.indexPathArray[recognizer.view.tag] as NSIndexPath
   let cell = self.tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)as customCell
   cell.testLabel.text = "Test"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView` follows the Model-View-Controller pattern. According to this pattern, all your changes need to be done to the model - in other words, to the data structure that stores the information from which you populate your cell data. Once you made the change to the model, you tell the view that the data has changed, which would then show the new data.

Let's say that your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function reads from an array. Your `imageSwiped` function should then locate the item that has been swiped, modify its entry in the array, and call either `reloadData` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`.

That's it! Once you notify the table view of the reload, it would go back to the array, find the modified data, and call your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to display it.

Specifically, in your code add an array called `swipedCells` to the same class where you declared `tableData` array:

```
var swipedCells = Boolean[](count:self.tableData.count, repeatedValue: false)
```

Now replace

```
cell.testLabel.text = "Test Label"
```

line with

```
if self.swipedCells[indexPath.row] {
    cell.testLabel.text = "Swiped!"
} else {
    cell.testLabel.text = "Test Label"
}
```

Finally, change the `imageSwiped` as follows:

```
let indexPathRow = self.indexPathArray[recognizer.view.tag] as Int
self.swipedCells[indexPathRow] = true
self.tableView?.reloadData()
```

This way the cells that you have swiped would continue to have a label `"Swiped!"` even after you scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after a huge amount of hours :D i solved my problem.

```
let indexPath = self.priceObjects[recognizer.view.tag] as NSIndexPath
let cell = self.tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)as customCell
```

i call this inside my imageSwipe function. Inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath function where i set the initial cell element values i store the indexPath inside an array. An i tag the Images to get a Index if the Swipe Events happens. I think it is far away from the ideal way...but works for me. I hope someday someone post the good way ;) cause this is very quick n' dirty.

Comment: This is an incorrect solution, because it goes straight to the view, bypassing the model. Although you can modify `cell`'s state in this way, it may change back to what it has been originally once you scroll the cell off the screen and bring it back. Did you try implementing the approach from my answer? How far did you go?

Comment: i tried but i in your solution you describe how i get the swiped image item. This is not my problem. I change the image after a swipe without a problem. But i want to change the Label above the image. This is my problem. I cant get reference of this specific label in the row. I updated my Question above.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer: getting the item is half the problem - the trick is how to get your label changed from within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If you update your question with the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code, I might be able to give you more specifics on how it is done.

Comment: Ok i updated my Question with the full function. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I was looking for your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Ok NOW i added everything :)